# Cannot log in to server after SSH port change

Tags: linux, ssh, port

I followed step one of this guide to change the SSH port of my server: http://www.linux.com/archive/articles/61061

Now, when I try to log in to it again by typing

```
    ssh -p 1234 user@my-server
```

I get the message

```
    Connection closed by xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

xxx being the IP address of my server.
Not using the -p option of using any other port results in the answer

```
    ssh: connect to host my-server.com port xxx: Connection refused
```

How can I connect to it again? It's a Debian machine, in case that matters.

Comment: Not ap rogramming question, superuser.com perhaps?

Comment: Is there a firewall involved?

Comment: @Kurt I think ServerFault is more appropriate here because we are dealing with sshd and possibly a firewall.

Comment: To debug ssh use -v -v -v -v -v -v

Comment: For future reference, after you make any change to an important service like sshd, ensure that you establish a new session successfully before you close the current session.  Restarting sshd does not affect existing ssh sessions, so if you've screwed it up you still have an active session to fix it.  If you don't follow this practice, you'll probably going to have to get console access (which may require physical access depending on the hardware) to fix the problem.

Comment: Thanks everybody! Seems like the server is indeed not accepting connections via the new port. Is there any other way I can get access again except from getting physical access to the machine? (which is gonna be quite difficult...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(As Kurt just mentioned) After having changed your default port in sshd_config, did you follow up by ensuring iptables was allowing inbound connections to your new port?

Comment: Don't post non-answer answers.

Comment: Telling someone to verify their their firewall is open IS an answer.  The phrasing used here is just a bit indirect...

Comment: Most likely this is the answer, that the server does not allow any inbound connections on that new port. Is there ANY chance I can get access to it? (physical access is not possible)

Answer (score 1):

Did you open a hole in the firewall?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, ensure that SSH is indeed running on the new port. On the server machine, run

```
netstat -untap
```

Check that `sshd` is listening on port 1234.

Next, check that there are no firewall rules blocking port 1234 anywhere along the network between your client machine and the server (including on the client and the server). By default, your Debian firewall rules should be clear unless you have changed them. However, if there is any other network device sitting between your client and server, it can still block that port.